# Android DateTime parse

Tags: java, android, datetime, datetime-format

How can I parse date time like this in Android

```
2014-05-19T07:16:29.63+00:00
```

? I've tried using `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSZZZZZ"` according to [SimpleDateFormatter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), but seems the result of `ZZZZZ` is the same as `Z`.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem by using [joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time)

Answer (score 1):

```
Z/ZZ/ZZZ: -0800

ZZZZ: GMT-08:00

ZZZZZ: -08:00
```

this is the difference.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, check the following notice at the [Home Page of Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/);

> Joda-Time is the de facto standard date and time library for Java
> prior to Java SE 8. Users are now asked to migrate to java.time
> (JSR-310).

**Solution using the modern API:**

The modern date-time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require you to use a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the date-time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards.

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2014-05-19T07:16:29.63+00:00");
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2014-05-19T07:16:29.630Z
```

The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

For any reason, if you need to convert this object of `OffsetDateTime` to an object of `java.util.Date`, you can do so as follows:

```
Date date = Date.from(odt.toInstant());
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try X for timezone, according to javadocs X is used for parsing given format. Note that for parsing the number of pattern letters does not matter.

Comment: OP is talking about Android-class, not Java-`SimpleDateFormat`.