# Kotlin - Unparseable date: "2021-07-20T12:35:07-07:00"

Tags: date, kotlin, parsing, simpledateformat

I'm getting an unparseable date exception using:

```
"2021-07-20T12:35:20-07:00".toDate()!!

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
fun String.toDate() : Date? {
    return SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").parse(this)
}
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It parses your string without you specifying any formatter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android DateTime parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23902492/android-datetime-parse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`SimpleDateFormat` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

> ```
> Z     Time zone   RFC 822 time zone   -0800
> X     Time zone   ISO 8601 time zone  -08; -0800; -08:00
> ```

The `Z` directive expects the time zone to be specified without a colon, whereas `X` allows a colon. Either format your dates like

```
2021-07-20T12:35:20-0700
```

or use the ISO 8601 timezone designator, rather than the RFC 822 one

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY4xC8IwEIX3/IqYpanQkEZEyOIi0qWTHVwDjRpN0pJeRRF/e70iiG@6e3f3vbt14F2cJhf6LgG9mrsRYB8gluTfGsF5tMhpjPQAycWzgG5nwPKcajoXW/oiFJUsjAmX8NrbebDvUjDA2RNV1HXRtlmTVZUOQQ/DkeWiN2mwHC5uyMn7GxGMi0ieiT2GgY@cKanKQm4KJZtS6dVaK4mtlpL9XlkskDBNHw)

Comment: Thank you sir, that seemed to fix the problem. I'll make sure to go through the docs as well!

Answer (score 1):

### java.time through desugaring

I recommend that you uses java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. Excuse my Java syntax:

```
public static OffsetDateTime toDate(String s) {
    return OffsetDateTime.parse(s);
}
```

Let’s try it:

```
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = toDate("2021-07-20T12:35:20-07:00");
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output is:

> 2021-07-20T12:35:20-07:00

We do not need to specify any formatter at all. Your string is in ISO 8601 format. `OffsetDateTime` and the other classes of java.time parse the  most common variants of ISO 8601 as their default, that is, without any explicit formatter. Which is good because as you experienced, constructing a formatter is error-prone.

In case you need a `Date` object for an old API not yet upgraded to Java time, the conversion is:

```
    Date oldfashionedDate = Date.from(dateTime.toInstant());
    System.out.println(oldfashionedDate);
```

Output (from a device in Europe/Brussels time zone):

> Tue Jul 20 21:35:20 CEST 2021

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)